# ld not finding existing library

Tags: linux, ld, gfortran, hdf5

I am compiling a fortran code that requires hdf5 libraries which are installed in a local directory. This is my Makefile:

```
FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -g -fcheck=all -Wall -fdefault-real-8
INCLUDES = -I/home/bharat/hdf5/include
LFLAGS = -L/home/bharat/hdf5/lib
LIBS= -lhdf5_fortran

main: main.o param.o dmotifs.o ssa.o
    $(FC) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o main $^

param.o: param.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<

dmotifs.o: dmotifs.f90 param.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<

ssa.o: ssa.f90 dmotifs.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<

main.o: main.f90 param.o dmotifs.o ssa.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $(INCLUDES) $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod *.MOD
```

During linking I get this error:

```
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:142: undefined reference to `__h5lib_MOD_h5open_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:143: undefined reference to `__h5f_MOD_h5fcreate_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:144: undefined reference to `__h5s_MOD_h5screate_simple_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:145: undefined reference to `__h5d_MOD_h5dcreate_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:158: undefined reference to `__h5d_provisional_MOD_h5dwrite_integer_3'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:147: undefined reference to `__h5d_MOD_h5dclose_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:148: undefined reference to `__h5s_MOD_h5sclose_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:149: undefined reference to `__h5s_MOD_h5screate_simple_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:150: undefined reference to `__h5d_MOD_h5dcreate_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:158: undefined reference to `__h5_dble_interface_MOD_h5dwrite_double_2'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:154: undefined reference to `__h5d_MOD_h5dclose_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:155: undefined reference to `__h5s_MOD_h5sclose_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:156: undefined reference to `__h5f_MOD_h5fclose_f'
/home/bharat/stochastic/main.f90:157: undefined reference to `__h5lib_MOD_h5close_f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

This typically happens when the the hdf-fortran library `libhdf5-fortran` is not specified. I made sure that the symlinks are pointing to the right locations. Adding `rpath` to the same lib directory also doesn't solve the problem. The library and the symlinks have read and execute permissions. I can't see where the problem is.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   5752246 May 23 03:24 libhdf5.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    431820 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_fortran.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      1035 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_fortran.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        25 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_fortran.so -> libhdf5_fortran.so.10.0.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        25 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5_fortran.so.10.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    355600 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_fortran.so.10.0.0*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    211088 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_hl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    150528 May 23 03:24 libhdf5hl_fortran.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      1126 May 23 03:24 libhdf5hl_fortran.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        27 May 23 03:24 libhdf5hl_fortran.so -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10.0.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        27 May 23 03:24 libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    112246 May 23 03:24 libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      1000 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_hl.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        20 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_hl.so -> libhdf5_hl.so.10.0.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        20 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_hl.so.10 -> libhdf5_hl.so.10.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    148227 May 23 03:24 libhdf5_hl.so.10.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       946 May 23 03:24 libhdf5.la*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      3266 May 23 03:24 libhdf5.settings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        17 May 23 03:24 libhdf5.so -> libhdf5.so.10.0.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root        17 May 23 03:24 libhdf5.so.10 -> libhdf5.so.10.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   3133678 May 23 03:24 libhdf5.so.10.0.0*
```

This worked fine in two other systems where `-libhdf5_fortran` was in `/lib64` (So I didn't have to specify library paths); gfortran version in these systems was (RH) 4.8.3 and ld version was 2.23.2. 
 In the current system the gfortran is 4.7.2 (ubuntu) and ld is 2.22.90.
I don't think that this is an issue of outdated versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
main: main.o param.o dmotifs.o ssa.o
    $(FC) $^ $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o main
```

instead of

```
main: main.o param.o dmotifs.o ssa.o
    $(FC) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o main $^
```

because linker flags should come last, otherwise it will silently discard the libraries because there are no unresolved symbols at the time the flags are processed.